# MS Word using POI4XPAGES

Tags: xpages

I am facing problem using the POI4Xpages with MSword 2016 version

Here is my setup details
- I have lotus notes client 9.0 FP1
- Installed POI4XPages server and designer client
- POI Xpages (1.3.1)
- I used MSWord2016

I'm able to get it setup running. My problem is that ,the first field (<>) inside the word document gets only get populated with values from the xpage document. There rest of fields inside the word document don't get the values populated.

For now I am trying to populate the first 3 fields into the word document.

I am attaching here my button code and WORD poi custom control

Thank you in advance.

***********This is my generate button***********

```
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                refreshMode="complete">
                <xp:this.action>
                    <xp:actionGroup>
                        <xp:executeScript>
                            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:try{
var doc = document1.getDocument(true);
viewScope.put("tmpf1",doc.getItemValueString("kindofCase"));
viewScope.put("tmpf2",doc.getItemValueString("TypeofCase"));
viewScope.put("tmpf3",doc.getItemValueString("cxExt15"));
viewScope.put("tmpf4",doc.getItemValueString("cxAmount"));
viewScope.put("tmpf5",doc.getItemValueString("cxClientName"));
viewScope.put("tmpf6",doc.getItemValueString("caseNum"));
viewScope.put("tmpf7",doc.getItemValueString("BenfAcct"));
viewScope.put("tmpf8",doc.getItemValueString("BenfBranch"));
viewScope.put("tmpf9",doc.getItemValueString("cxDLQ"));
viewScope.put("tmpf10",doc.getItemValueString("cxForm1"));
viewScope.put("tmpf11",doc.getItemValueString("cxForm2"));
viewScope.put("tmpf12",doc.getItemValueString("cxRecRequestvia"));
viewScope.put("tmpf13",doc.getItemValueString("cxChannel"));
viewScope.put("tmpf14",doc.getItemValueString("BenfBank"));
viewScope.put("tmpf15",doc.getItemValueString("BenfName"));
viewScope.put("tmpf16",doc.getItemValueString("BenfID"));
viewScope.put("tmpf17",doc.getItemValueString("cxLength4"));
viewScope.put("tmpf18",doc.getItemValueString("BenfNationality"));
viewScope.put("tmpf19",doc.getItemValueString("BenfState"));
viewScope.put("tmpf20",doc.getItemValueString("BenfCity"));

//print (viewScope.tmpf2);
} catch (e){
    print (e);
}}]]></xp:this.script>
                        </xp:executeScript>
                        <wgpoi:generateDocument documentId="wb"></wgpoi:generateDocument>
                    </xp:actionGroup>
                </xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:button>
```

**************POI word custom control **************

```
<wgpoi:document id="wb" downloadFileName="whistleblower.docx"
            pathInfo="download">
            <wgpoi:this.templateSource>
                <wgpoi:resourcetemplate fileName="word2016.docx"></wgpoi:resourcetemplate>
            </wgpoi:this.templateSource>
            <wgpoi:this.bookmarks>
                <wgpoi:docbookmark value="#{javascript:viewScope.tmpf1}"
                    name="field1">
                </wgpoi:docbookmark>
                <wgpoi:docbookmark value="#{javascript:viewScope.tmpf2}"
                    name="field2">
                </wgpoi:docbookmark>
                <wgpoi:docbookmark value="#{javascript:viewScope.tmpf3}"
                    name="field3">
                </wgpoi:docbookmark>
            </wgpoi:this.bookmarks>
        </wgpoi:document>
```

Comment: Is it because the second field is used as "tmp2" instead of "tmpf2" and third field is read from wbdoc instead from doc?

Comment: Hi Knut, Thank you for noticing the error in my code . I have corrected it now and populating into the word document is not working. It only takes the 1st field. the codes above is now revised after your obersvation

Comment: Are the fields of *TypeOfCase* and *cxExt15* String values? Are the viewScope variables correctly set?

Comment: Have you switched off spellchecker? For some not understandable reasons, spellchecker is altering the XML Format in the backend and POI4XPages is not capable to find the <field3> value, because they are no longer in the same <run> element in the backend.

Comment: Hi Sven, Thanks for the update. Yes the fields are of Text type

Comment: Hi Christian, yes the spell checker is turned off on this word document. May I know which version of MS word the sample poi db is using. Thank you for the update

Comment: Hi All, Here is what I did , I created a new MS document(new) and copy over the original MS document provided to me. Then I notice, the sample(POI) was using font=Times New Roman, and walah it works like a charm. Another observation if ever I just replace the file resource with the update MSWord , changes are not reflected. The workaround I use , create new empty MSword with Times Romans fonts and copy over the MS word and attached to file resource. Thank you all for given attention to my topic.